# Recyclerview items background change in itemclick

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Here i have list of items in recyclerview which is fetching from firebase. so i am trying to change its background color when user clicks on it. but when i click on item 1 then item 4 background color also getting changed. and if click on item 2 then item 8 color also. its giving improper result.

```
    firebaseTimeadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TimeSlot, FirebaseTimeViewHolder>(
            TimeSlot.class,
            R.layout.time_slot_layout,
            FirebaseTimeViewHolder.class,
            timeSlot.child(Common.BikeId)) {
        //variable to hold selected Item position
        private int mSelectedItemPosition = -1;



        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final FirebaseTimeViewHolder firebaseTimeViewHolder, TimeSlot slot, final int i) {
            firebaseTimeViewHolder.time_slot.setText(slot.getTime_slot());
            firebaseTimeViewHolder.txt_time_slot_description.setText(ConvertToAvailableorNotAvailable(slot.isAvailable()));
            firebaseTimeViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                    firebaseTimeViewHolder.card_view_slot.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));

                    firebaseTimeViewHolder.card_view_slot.setClickable(false);

                    firebaseTimeViewHolder.time_slot.setTextColor(getResources()
                            .getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    firebaseTimeViewHolder.txt_time_slot_description.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));


                      //  firebaseTimeViewHolder.card_view_slot.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
                        date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM").format(new Date());
                        txt_from_date.setText(date + " " + slot.getTime_slot());
                    //    Toast.makeText(BookingCalender.this, "Clicked" + slot.getTime_slot(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

        }
    };
    recycler_time_list.setAdapter(firebaseTimeadapter);
```

View holder class

```
public class FirebaseTimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView time_slot,txt_time_slot_description;
public CardView card_view_slot;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;




public FirebaseTimeViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    time_slot=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_slot);
    txt_time_slot_description=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_slot_description);
    card_view_slot=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_time_slot);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
    this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this non-sense part and just use `itemView.setOnClickListener()`:

```
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

Also this part is quite strange; in best case it will cause an endless loop:

```
itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);
```

This should at least cure the abnormal behavior caused by setting all items to the same listener ...

---

While I think you might be looking for something alike [`androidx.recyclerview.selection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary):

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.0.0"
```

See [A guide to recyclerview-selection](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504), below "Step 5: Highlighting the selected items".

Nevertheless, one could persist the selection better with data-binding & a database.

Comment: explanation code is not in java. i am not sure how to implement in java. could you please help me @Martin Zeitler